# Typedoc throws error with the require syntax

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, typedoc

I am trying to generate documentation using typedoc. I have the following lines in my typescript file.

```
var validator: any = require('validator');
import * as _ from 'lodash';
var mqtt: any = require('mqtt');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var tls = require('tls');
import * as collections from 'typescript-collections';
```

here, the require lines and lodash lines are throwing the following error.

[image]

Below is my config.

```
gulp.task('typedoc',['clean-doc'], function () {
  return gulp
    .src(path.join(conf.paths.src, conf.path_pattern.ts))
    .pipe($.typedoc({
      module: tsConf.module,
      target: tsConf.target,
      includeDeclarations: false,

      out: conf.paths.docs,
      json: path.join(conf.paths.docs, conf.files.JSON_DOC),

      name: conf.files.PROJECT_NAME,
      ignoreCompilerErrors: true,
      excludeExternals:true,
      version: true

    }))
    .on('error', conf.errorHandler(conf.errors.title.TYPESCRIPT));
});
```

Why am I getting this error? How can I get over this? Please advice.

Comment: I'm not sure, but version: true might be interpreted like --version, thus typedoc simply emits the version and quits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add global typings path(typings/index.d.ts) to the gulp task **typedoc** src.

```
 return gulp
.src([["data/*.ts","typings/index.d.ts"])
```